# How to remove html elements from a string but exclude a specific element with regex

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

I have a string `'<span>TEST1</span> <span>TEST2</span> <a href="#">TEST3</a>'`

I need to remove html tags and leave the text

```
import re
p = re.compile( '\s*<[^>]+>\s*')
test = p.sub('', '<span>TEST1</span> <span>TEST2</span> <a href="#">TEST3</a>')
print(test)
```

OUTPUT: `TEST1TEST2TEST3`

But this removes every html element, how should I change regex so that the output would be like this:

```
OUTPUT: TEST1 TEST2 <a href="#">TEST3</a>
```

Comment: Better solution is to use HTML parser. Are you open to using `beautifulsoup` ?

Comment: The pattern matches all elements because it matches from `<...>` You could change it to `<(?!\/a>|a )[^>]+>` https://regex101.com/r/YxTzLr/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the so-called "[Negative Lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)".

In your case, you can leave out `<a`  and `</a>`:

`(?!<a )(?!<\/a>)<[^>]+>`

Note the space in `<a`  and the closing parenthesis in `</a>` so that only the opening and closing tags of an `<a>` element match and nothing else begins with an a.